# How to rewrite this sum

Tags: analysis

Hi I have the following problem: I have to show that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sign(\sigma)v^{\sigma(2)}w^{\sigma(3)}\partial_{x^i}$$
$$=$$
$$(v^2w^3-v^3w^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x^1}}+(v^3w^1-v^1w^3)\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x^2}}+(v^1w^2-v^2w^1)\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x^3}}$$
Until now I have the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^3(v^2w^3-v^3w^2-v^1w^3+v^3w^1+v^1w^2-v^2w^1)\partial_{x^i}$$
Can someone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, no one can help you here, because what you are trying to prove is false. Your calculation is correct. The extra terms do not cancel out or go away. I suspect an issue in the problem statement, as the RHS is $$\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sign(\sigma)v^{\sigma(2)}w^{\sigma(3)}\partial{x^{\sigma(1)}}$$